# Is this circuit linear or not?

Tags: mosfet, driver, linear

I designed a current source circuit for driving LEDs. This circuit works fine and supplies constant 2.5A. I wonder if this circuit is linear or not.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuRvka.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

1-) If this circuit is linear;

V<sub>LOAD</sub> = 9VDC and V<sub>in</sub> = 16VDC and V<sub>DS-M1</sub> = 6VDC. The Power dissipated by MOSFET would be as:
P = 6 * 2.5 => 15W
Rth = 62 °C/W so MOSFET temperature should increase by 62.5 * 15 = 938°C but it only increased by 50°C. So I think this circuit is not linear.

Also I scoped the gate voltage using an oscilloscope and there is a switching:
[image]

2-) If this circuit is not linear;

If this circuit is not linear, I<sub>in</sub> and I<sub>out</sub> should not be equal but they are totally equal.

Am I wrong? How can we characterize this circuit?

Comment: *I wonder if this circuit is linear or not.* You should explain what you mean by "linear". You mention Iin and Iout but I see no Iin in the schematic. I could easily say that this **is** a linear circuit in the sense that it regulates the current in a linear way, so not by **switching** but probably that's not what you mean. So be clear what you mean.

Comment: Looking at that oscillogram though, it is switching at about 50MHz, so it's not linear in the sense of a classic linear regulator.

Comment: Also I think I see what this circuit is trying to achieve, R5 and R6 make a "reference" voltage (from the supply) and that voltage is (linearly) converted into a current by the opamp+ NMOS with source resistor. The current then drives a LED. **However** I expect this circuit to **have issues** and I think the switching you see is that issue, it is actually **oscillating**. Using a **comparator**, the LM211 in a feedback loop as if it is an opamp is **asking for trouble**.

Comment: In an attempt to make it stable there's a large capacitor C1. The fact that you still see an oscillation means this isn't helping. I suggest removing C1 and R8 as well and using a **proper** opamp like an LM124.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie The necessary modifications have been done in the schematic. He meant "linear regulator" by the term "linear". One could easily say that the circuit should act as a linear regulator since both input and output currents are nearly equal. But the thing that prevents him to say so is the existence of the switching signal at the gate. I think the same alternating signal can be scoped across the current sense resistor as well.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I added C7 capacitor to kill the buzzing noise. If I don't place it, the circuit switches or oscillates at about 8kHz. The funny thing is that the "oscillation" frequency totally depends on the R7 (e.g. f<sub>SW</sub>=17kHz for R7=12k).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

\$R_{\theta JA}\$ is one small part of the story. The main part of the story is \$R_{\theta JC}\$ (at 1.5 °C/W), because this is the junction-to-case thermal resistance and it adds to the heatsink thermal resistance to give the lowest (normally) path for heat.

So, if the thermal resistance of the heatsink is (say) 6 °C/W then the total thermal resistance that matters is 7.5 °C/W (plus the typical figure of 0.5 °C/W for the interface between transistor case and heatsink). A total of about 8 °C/W.

Therefore 17.5 watts would heat the junction by an extra 140 °C for a 6 °C/W heatsink. In an ambient of 25 °C this means a junction temperature of 165 °C and pretty close to the 175 °C limit for the device.

You also need to ensure that local ambient doesn't rise due to this heatflow. It could easily rise by another 20 °C if the heat is not effectively taken away. So now you might be into the wrong side of the specification and you should expect trouble if the heatsink is only 6 °C/W.

Given that you only saw a temperature increase of 50 °C I suspect you are using a heatsink with thermal resistance much lower than what I guessed at.

> Also I scoped the gate voltage using an oscilloscope and there is a
>   switching.

You have a 2 µF capacitor on the op-amp output, and this massively alters the open loop gain of that part. Basically it takes it several steps forward to becoming an oscillator due to the extra (almost) 90 degrees phase shift you have added due to the 2 µF capacitor and the op-amp's output resistance of several ohms. Don't do this.

You are also using an LM211 and that part is a comparator - these are not guaranteed to be stable with negative feedback, so this is another problem. You have a few problems here.

Comment: Thanks for your advices. @Bimpelrekkie suggests the same thing. I will try changing opamp and design this circuit again to remove C1 capacitor. It will take some time. I will share the result.

Comment: @wooz make sure you use a proper op-amp and, if you still get oscillations try a 10 nF capacitor from op-amp output to inverting input. You will still need R2 for this type of filtering to work. R7 and R8 won't be needed.

Comment: @PeterMortensen thanks for the edit. I have approved it but have changed your use of the hyphen in the 2uF bit to a space as that is what is technically correct.

Comment: I designed new circuit as your suggested using lm324 but lm324 did not drive MOSFET. So i had to add transistor circuit to drive MOSFET and it worked. Instead of this circuit i did some improvment at previous circuit to supress oscillation.  
1-)C1 capacitor and R7 resistor have been removed. 
2-)100nF capacitors to the LM211 inputs and 1k2 have been added to the emiter output. 
3-)R8 resistor value has been changed to the 10kohm.
4-)100ohm resistor has been added to the gate.

Comment: @wooz glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no connection between "circuit is linear" and \$P=(V_{in}-V_{out})*I\$. Your circuit is non-linear because it has non-linear components: a MOSFET, some LEDs and a comparator.

Also, ignoring small losses in the resistors, your circuit has a single contour so \$I_{in}\$ will be the same as \$I_{out}\$ no matter what.